# How do you say "ragdoll physics" into Chinese?

Tags: translation, word-choice, word, terminology

When your avatar dies in a game, it will swingy （一摆一摆的）. Like with games like Roblox, GMod, or Human Fall Flat; its physics is designed that way.

In Wikipedia, "Ragdoll physics" is translated as "布娃娃系统". However, I am wondering if there is a better translation in Chinese that incorporates the understanding of 一摆一摆的.

---

Updated understanding based on your responses:
**布娃娃系统**用的物理是叫做“**布偶物理**”。它是指在游戏中的一种物理。随着角色的移动，它的身体也会伴随着摆动。
（The physics used in the ragdoll system is called "ragdoll physics". It refers to a type of physics in the game. As the character moves, its body will also swing.）

---

***布*娃娃系统 = *Rag*doll System**; 布娃娃 is translated literally as ragdoll.

**布偶物理：= Ragdoll Physics**; 布偶 is translated literally as "puppet".

Comment: Ragdoll physics - 布偶物理.

Comment: That sounds very correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "physics"? of a ragdoll is simply: a ragdoll is extremely flexible and can be bent and or folded in any direction. I think they mean: the physical properties of a ragdoll.

Physics is a science whose rules should apply to all objects.

游戏角色倒下时会伴随身体的摆动.
When a game character falls, the body will sway.

Comment: Wooo. I think "伴随身体的摇动“ is a pretty good way to describe it!